# Rewrite rule multiple folders

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I can't figure out how to rewrite a rule for .htaccess
And if it's even possible.
What am I doing wrong because this eg isn't working.

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule (.*)information/(.*)$ information.php?slug=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule (.*)informatie/search/(.*)$ informatie-search.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

The first rewrite rule is called when website.com/information/content is used  (I do a query on that page on what comes after /content so eg. website.com/information/content/locations)

The second rewrite rule is called when website.com/information/search is used  (I do a query on that page on what comes after /search so eg. website.com/information/search/books)

Comment: There is no actual, discernible question here. What exactly is your problem with the code you have shown us? Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Is `informatie` in the second rule a typo? You said the URL was actually `/information/search`. (In that case, you have to reverse the order of the two rules of course, otherwise the first one will capture `/information/search` already.)

Answer (score 0):

I modified rules, please check it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # /information/any to /information.php?slug=any
    RewriteRule ^information\/(.*)$ /information.php?slug=$1 [L]

    # /informatie/search/any to /informatie-search.php?slug=any
    RewriteRule ^informatie\/search\/(.*)$ /informatie-search.php?slug=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```